# Modify files one at a time

Tags: node.js, json, typescript

I am using a JSON file as the database, so I need to eliminate `read/write` errors while the file has not been fully updated.

How do I create a queue of update processes from the same file?

(I'm using typescript)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `bull`, it is a third-part well tested queue library. You can install it using npm:

```
npm install bull --save
```

To add types run this:

```
npm install @types/bull --save-dev
```

You can follow these steps:

```
const Queue = require('bull');

const videoQueue = new Queue('video transcoding', 'redis://127.0.0.1:6379');
const audioQueue = new Queue('audio transcoding', { redis: { port: 6379, host: '127.0.0.1', password: 'foobared' } }); // Specify Redis connection using object
const imageQueue = new Queue('image transcoding');
const pdfQueue = new Queue('pdf transcoding');

videoQueue.process(function (job, done) {

  // job.data contains the custom data passed when the job was created
  // job.id contains id of this job.

  // transcode video asynchronously and report progress
  job.progress(42);

  // call done when finished
  done();

  // or give a error if error
  done(new Error('error transcoding'));

  // or pass it a result
  done(null, { framerate: 29.5 /* etc... */ });

  // If the job throws an unhandled exception it is also handled correctly
  throw new Error('some unexpected error');
});

audioQueue.process(function (job, done) {
  // transcode audio asynchronously and report progress
  job.progress(42);

  // call done when finished
  done();

  // or give a error if error
  done(new Error('error transcoding'));

  // or pass it a result
  done(null, { samplerate: 48000 /* etc... */ });

  // If the job throws an unhandled exception it is also handled correctly
  throw new Error('some unexpected error');
});

imageQueue.process(function (job, done) {
  // transcode image asynchronously and report progress
  job.progress(42);

  // call done when finished
  done();

  // or give a error if error
  done(new Error('error transcoding'));

  // or pass it a result
  done(null, { width: 1280, height: 720 /* etc... */ });

  // If the job throws an unhandled exception it is also handled correctly
  throw new Error('some unexpected error');
});

pdfQueue.process(function (job) {
  // Processors can also return promises instead of using the done callback
  return pdfAsyncProcessor();
});

videoQueue.add({ video: 'http://example.com/video1.mov' });
audioQueue.add({ audio: 'http://example.com/audio1.mp3' });
imageQueue.add({ image: 'http://example.com/image1.tiff' });
```

You can check the documentation of [bull](https://www.npmjs.com/package/bull) to implement it.

Note: If you don't get the gist of how to implement it, I recommend you to follow [this](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-implement-queues-in-node-js-8b3a06ce0dd0) link.